# Load external classes

Tags: java, reflection, urlclassloader

I am trying to load external classes in my project.
My idea is to load a class and then use reflection to get its properties and methods.

I am trying to do this, but it doesnt work

```
        Path destination = Paths.get("C:\\Project\\src\\com\\test\\TestLauncher.java");

        URL[] classUrls = new URL[]{ new File(destination.subpath(0, destination.getNameCount()).toString()).toURL() };

        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);

        Class<?> beanClass = ucl.loadClass("com.test.TestLauncher");
```

This code works as a charm when you try to use it in files in the same project but it doesn't work when the class is not in the same project, in this case I get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.FileToLoad     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   urlLoader.Play.main(Play.java:26)

Comment: You must load your class from a compiled `.class` file.

Comment: In my code I compile it with parameters, like this:  String command = "javac -parameters " + destination.toAbsolutePath().toString();
            
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

Comment: How do you compile the Java source file does not matter here. The `destination` variable needs to be changed to the path to your .class file.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to compile .java file and try to load .class file.

Also you get `TestLauncher.java` file but try to load `com.test.FileToLoad`.

Try this:

```
// path to base directory with classes (exclude packages)
File file = new File("C:\\Project\\target\\classes");
URL[] classUrls = new URL[]{ file.toURI().toURL() };
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);
Class<?> beanClass = ucl.loadClass("com.test.TestLauncher");
```

Comment: You are right, I cleaned the code a little to put here and I misstranslate this

Comment: In my code I compile it with parameters, like this: String command = "javac -parameters " + destination.toAbsolutePath().toString(); Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
I can see the compiled class next to the .java

Comment: One last thing, could I know the name of the class (the one used in loadClass method) using the classLoader item, I dont find the way to get it

Comment: I have realized it is not working, it just worked because the class was in both packages, the one I try to import and the one I use to get it

Comment: @DavidMarciel Can you show what you actually do? I tried it before type this code here.